# daily traffic flow prediction with Python pandas

Tags: pandas, time-series, prediction

I have got a traffic flow data set about one road of a city, in the interval of a minute, new data are real time and keep coming.  Based on my current data, I found that the traffic has a daily pattern, i.e, similar peaks during specific period of time.

I have used Python pandas for the prediction, mainly stats models such as ARMA. I have used 3-min average traffic window to smooth the data. Right now the accuracy is about 15% in terms of error relative ratio.

I just wonder is there any way I can improve the accuracy, especially how I can take advantage of the daily pattern property.

Thanks

Comment: Can provide part of your data as the example?

Comment: you are refering to ARMA model or how I get the data? For the former, it is in the pandas library. For the latter, I have used request package from python, it is straightforward

Comment: Specific questions, showing succinct snippets of work code, generally elicit better answers. For example, can you show a sample of your data and the results from the model?

Comment: The data is organized as follow: 
1   34;
2   23;
3   15;
......
where 1st column indicates the moment at specified minute, the 2nd column represents the number of vehicles passing this road